# Importing ca-certificate chain (.crt) - RHEL7

Tags: redhat, certificate-authority

I am fairly new to this but I've done some internet research the last 2 days and I couldn't find an suitable answer.

I have been given a ca-certificate chain (*cacertchain.crt*) which I need to import to a server running RHEL7 (no GUI). The server has the *ca-bundle.crt* file. I have tried to put *cacertchain.crt* to */etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/* and run `update-ca-trust` and `update-ca-trust extract` but I couldn't see any changes to the ca-bundle.crt file.

So my question: is there a way of importing a ca-certificate chain (.crt) to RHEL7 keystore?

The certificate chain (cacertchain.crt) includes:

> Root Certificate Subject CN - VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary
> Certification Authority - G5 (I believe this is already available in
> ca-bundle.crt)
>
> Intermediate Certificate Subject CN - Symantec Class 3 EV SSL CA - G3

Comment: Import it where?

Comment: I just want to add/import it to the server's trusted keystore. As far as I understand for RHEL7 would be the ca-bundle.crt file. I could be wrong though.

Comment: For what purpose? There is no global keystore on Linux operating systems.

Comment: In addition to Michael's comment, some of the default applications Red Hat ships do use a central location, as documented in [RHEL  solution 1549003](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1549003), but many more do not and will need an application specific configuration...

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I though ca-bundle.crt was used as a global keystore. The certs are required by an httpd application (for external connections).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I appears by including the ca-cert bundle in `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/` and running `update-ca-trust extract` worked fine.

Comment: In my case I needed to install an intermediate (instead of a Root) cert, on release 7.6. After a look at a README file in /etc/pki/ca-trust, I opted for putting the cert retrieved from CA's website into `/usr/share/pki/ca-trust-source/anchors/` and then run just `update-ca-trust` and it worked fine for me. Also quick tip to help verify results:  `trust list | grep label ; trust list | grep label | wc -l`

Answer (score 5):

Copy the certificates to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` and after that execute `update-ca-trust extract`.

They should be available to all application that check that path for certificates (for example `wget` and `curl`).

Answer (score 1):

3 steps works for me on this cases:

1. certificate to /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
2. update-ca-trust force-enable
3. update-ca-trust extract

Answer (score 1):

## Disambiguation

I think the given answers and comments are mixing up two different cases.

Accoding to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/README`:

```
This directory /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/ contains CA certificates and 
trust settings in the PEM file format. The trust settings found here will be
interpreted with a high priority - higher than the ones found in 
/usr/share/pki/ca-trust-source/.

=============================================================================
QUICK HELP: To add a certificate in the simple PEM or DER file formats to the
            list of CAs trusted on the system:

            Copy it to the
                    /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
            subdirectory, and run the
                    update-ca-trust
            command.

            If your certificate is in the extended BEGIN TRUSTED file format,
            then place it into the main source/ directory instead.
=============================================================================

Please refer to the update-ca-trust(8) manual page for additional information.
```

Note this paragraph:

> If your certificate is in the extended BEGIN TRUSTED file format,
> then place it into the main source/ directory instead.

In case you want to install a **`.crt`** file:

1. Copy:

   ```
   cp extendedcert.crt /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/
   ```
2. Apply:

   ```
   update-ca-trust
   ```

In case you want to install a **`.cer`** file:

1. Copy:

   ```
   cp simplecert.cer /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/
   ```
2. Apply:

   ```
   update-ca-trust
   ```