# Self-signed Cert for yum repository server

Tags: ssl, redhat, centos7, yum, repository

Can I use Self-signed Cert for local yum repository server?

The problem is when a client i sdoing a `yum update` via my repository server, it shows

> [Errno 14] curl#60 - "Peer's certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user."

Is there anyway that I can connect to the repository server via HTTPS (port 443) rather than port 80?

Thanks!!!

Comment: You could try to set `sslverify = False` for this specific repository.

Answer (score 3):

[Importing ca-certificate chain (.crt) - RHEL7](https://serverfault.com/q/739980/241174)

Copy the cert to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/` and run `update-ca-trust extract`

If you had an existing PKI to deploy this with like 
Red Hat Certificate System, use that instead.

Comment: still the same issue :(

Comment: @DavidA: did you find the solution to your problem?